# You should specify a parent contact or account error in Dynamics CRM

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to create a new incident through postman in Dynamics CRM but I am getting the following error:

> You should specify a parent contact or account

Which I assumed that is asking for `customerid` to be sent so I added it on postman like:

```
{
    "description": "Test",
    "ed_egresssenttorentadmin": true, 
    "note['_customerid_value@odata.bind']":"f686f062-e542-e811-a955-000d3ab27a43",
    "note['_ownerid_value@odata.bind']":"a7b7fcb7-a64e-e811-a96f-000d3ab384bc"
}
```

but I still get the same error, any idea on how to set `accountId` when creating a new `incident` ?

Comment: `f686f062-e542-e811-a955-000d3ab27a43` is the GUID of the Account (`customerid`)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [RESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) it should look something like this.

```
entity["customerid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(f686f062-e542-e811-a955-000d3ab27a43)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the basic payload needed to create an incident:

```
{
  "title": "case test",
  "customerid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(f686f062-e542-e811-a955-000d3ab27a43)"
}
```